# How to calculate test statistic when $H_0$ is not equal

Tags: hypothesis-testing

So I'm trying to perform a $t$ test with sample mean $\bar{x}$ and sample variance $s^2$. I know how to do this with $H_0 = a$ and $H_a \ne a$. But now I'm given $H_0 < a$ and $H_a \ge a$. How do I modify the $t$ test formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you should use [one tailed test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-_and_two-tailed_tests).
When $H_0 : \mu<a$, it is not strange that $t=\frac{\overline{x}-a}{\sqrt{\frac{s^2}{n}}}$ is negative. So, even when $t$ is $-500$, $H_0$ is not rejeted. However, t is larger than $t_\alpha$(not $t_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$), it is rejected.

Comment: So I would still plug constant $a$ into the function like normal? I thought I have to like pick a value $< a$

Comment: Yes. In fact, normally we think that $H_0:\mu=a$ and $H_1:\mu>a$. I think you say about this pattern. However, if you say about another pattern, this answer is not useful for your question. Soery.